# How to Ignore given id during validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

> Do not down vote this question, I know it has been asked before but, I
>   couldn't find any with working answer!

I'm trying to have a unique email, but ignore a given id during validation.
Tried a few methods to get this done, here is two of them which were promising yet, did not work:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'username' => ['username', Rule::unique('user', 'username')->ignore($user->id)]
]);
```

another one:

```
'username' => 'required|max:30,',
Rule::unique('user')->ignore($user->id),
```

thanks for and help.

This is some more information in case you think the aboce examples should definnetaly work.
Form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="formClasses" id="usernameLocal"
 value="{{ Auth::user()->username }}">
```

Controller:

```
public function saveUserChanges(Request $request){

    $user = Auth::user();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|max:30,',
        Rule::unique('user')->ignore($user->id)
    ]);

    $user->username = $request['username'];

    $user->update();

    return redirect()->route('userProfil', $user->userprofile->slug);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update $user? Or do you passing the user_id with the request?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to edit that user's username

Comment: Can you show the controller and form?

Comment: well I can but don't you think that it's gonna get confusing?

Comment: How do you get the $user object?[we can reduce no of comments if you are adding the code]

Comment: yeap just added all you need

Comment: By the way, can you vote my question up? that way I might get a better chance to have it solved

Comment: Try changing `$this->validate($request, ['username' => 'required|max:30,',Rule::unique('user')->ignore($user->id)]);` to `$request->validate(['username' => ['required', 'max:30', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)] ]);`

Comment: I don't think there is a valid reason for an upvote.[Also **not** down voting]

Comment: The electrocity went down a while ago for some reason. i will try it as soon as it comes back. Sry for making you wait

Comment: @ab_ab I tried it, nothing changes

Comment: ypur code throws "Method validate does not exist" error, this is the weirders thing I have ever seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to guarantee a unique email the rule will be the following:

```
Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

If your field is not `email` in your users table then do this:

```
Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users', 'column_name')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Lastly if your unique id on the users table is not `id` then do:

```
Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users', 'column_name')->ignore($user->id, 'unique_key_name'),
    ],
]);
```

To use your code directly it would look like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'username' => [
            'required',
            'max:30',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)
        ]
    ]);
```

The changes I made were the required and max rule need to be separated, and all of the rules needed to be in an array. I also changed the table from `user` to `users` as that is the Laravel default.

See the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique

Comment: I just tried what you've gven here and nothing has changed. Btw I do not see any difference between this and the code I gave above

Comment: Then you did it wrong, you did not wrap your rules in an array [], they need to be an array

Comment: @Nikonah I have updated my answer with the code that you would use based on what was in your controller in your question

Comment: Well, that works perfectly, thanks for helping out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: But I still don't know what was the error, perhapes it's becouse I didnt put it inside brackets

Comment: @Nikonah there were a few issues, 1 was that required and max needed to be separate, 2 was that all the rules following username needed to be in an array, 3 was that you had user instead of users, the table name is always a plural of the Model unless it is overridden with $tablename on the model.